# What is the right way to handle multiple simultaneous features in parallel development?

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

We have been using git-flow for development, with integration, QA, and live environments. It's not working for us - we frequently have multiple features in parallel development by disparate teams, and regularly find that some features are ready to go live to master while other features have already been merged to the develop branch but haven't yet been sufficiently integration tested. We then end up holding up the release until all of the features in the pipeline are tested and freezing develop for the duration, which is an inconvenience for developers who are working on new features. Some people have suggested using only one branch and developing with feature flags instead, but that presents its own set of challenges.

Is there a good way to bundle commits together so they can be carried forward as a group? We have each feature on a separate branch, but that grouping is lost when the feature branch is merged back to develop. What I think would help is to keep the branch intact and then merge it forward into master when that feature has been tested and is ready to go live, but this doesn't seem to be easy.

We are also open to moving to a different source control system if there's something else that would make this easier, but whatever system we end up with must also support selective merging based on the success or failure of automated tests (we use jenkins for this now).

What's the best way to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Some people have suggested using only one branch and developing with feature flags instead

You definitely should listen to these people. In my experience this is the best way to integrate software in any bigger project.

It is not only that it will make your release planning easier but also various other benefits such as:

- It will allow your developers to integrate early and often and even unfinished code. This will reduce the integration risk between the development branches. And gives better visibility/sync between the features.
- It will create a positive competition for integrating your changes early because that is the way to avoid merge conflicts.
- If you only have one branch, you can concentrate all your testing efforts on this branch.

Recommended reading: [Martin Fowler about Feature branches](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html)

Comment: I've read that. It seems like adding feature flags will massively complicate the codebase, increase the ramp-up time for new developers, be prone to errors in implementation and removal, complicate testing, and increase the amount of communication *required* among the different teams. More recommended reading: http://swreflections.blogspot.com/2014/08/feature-toggles-are-one-of-worst-kinds.html

Comment: If your developers are working on a shared codebase increasing communication is solely a good thing. If you want to limit the communication then split the codebase into totally independent responsibility areas that have well designed and backward compatible APIs. (But in most cases this is going to be very inflexible)

Comment: Increased developer communication is a good thing in general, but artificially increasing the amount of mandatory communication by introducing structural overhead that requires it is not a great goal.

Comment: It is great that you have read the Fowler. I have in turn read the article you linked. It has some great advices and you certainly should be careful when introducing feature toggles. Still I would say that it will be way less painful once your team learn to use them.

Here is some more single track propaganda :)
https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/